# Trying to set a listener for Firebase chat messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am trying to set a listener for Firebase to get new chat messages and send them to a recycler view in a fragment, but I keep getting two errors:

The first error is on "Data" in setupAdapter and the second error is on message.timestamp.

Type Mismatch:

```
Required:
kotlin.collections.ArrayList<com.ntx_deisgns.cyberchatter.cyberchatter.Message> /* = java.util.ArrayList<com.ntx_deisgns.cyberchatter.cyberchatter.Message> */
Found:
kotlin.collections.ArrayList<android.os.Message> /* = java.util.ArrayList<android.os.Message> */
```

And

```
Unresolved reference: timestamp
```

Here's the code in my fragment class:

```
private fun createFirebaseListener(){
        val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                val toReturn: ArrayList<Message> = ArrayList();

                for(data in dataSnapshot.children){
                    val messageData = data.getValue<Message>(Message::class.java)

                    //unwrap
                    val message = messageData?.let { it } ?: continue

                    toReturn.add(message)
                }

                //sort so newest at bottom
                toReturn.sortBy { message ->
                    message.timestamp
                }

                setupAdapter(toReturn)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                //log error
            }
        }
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef = database.getReference("message")
        val mDatabase: DatabaseReference? = myRef

        mDatabase?.child("Group Chat")?.addValueEventListener(postListener)
    }

    /**
     * Once data is here - display it
     */
    private fun setupAdapter(data: ArrayList<Message>){
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        viewAdapter = MessageAdapter(data) {
//            Toast.makeText(this, "${it.text} clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        //scroll to bottom
        mainActivityRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(data.size - 1)
    }
```

I have created a class called Message.kt and that is where it is trying to pull from.  Here is that code as well just in case:

package com.ntx_deisgns.cyberchatter.cyberchatter

```
class Message {

    constructor() //empty for firebase

    constructor(messageText: String){
        text = messageText
    }
    var text: String? = null
    var timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

I thought would be a fairly simple and straightforward task but it is turning out not a simple as I was thinking.  What exactly am I missing here that is preventing me from doing this correctly?

Comment: You are referring to the wrong message class in the class import section. 
android.os.Message instead of com.ntx_deisgns.cyberchatter.cyberchatter.Message

Comment: I am referring to the "Data" of the `viewAdapter = MessageAdapter(data)` and the "timestamp " of the `message.timestamp`

Comment: Right you are. Please add the import statements you are using in this class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had `import android.os.Message` which was importing the wrong class.  I needed to only have `import com.ntx_deisgns.cyberchatter.cyberchatter.Message` to import my Message class.  Issue resolved.